# Tokenize big files to hashtable in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, corpus

I'm having this problem: I'm reading 900 files and, after processing the files, my final output will be an `HashMap<String, <HashMap<String, Double>>`. First string is fileName, second string is word and the double is word frequency. The processing order is as follows:

- read the first file

  - read the first line of the file
  - split the important tokens to a string array
  - copy the string array to my final map, incrementing word frequencies
- repeat for all files

I'm using string `BufferedReader`. The problem is, after processing the first files, the Hash becomes so big that the performance is very low after a while. I would like to hear solution for this. My idea is to create a limited hash, after the limit reached store into a file. do that until everything is processed, mix all the hashs at the end.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the data in the corpus?  It doesn't sound like, say, English text...  or how are you splitting them?  Are the tokens much the same in all files i.e. you could intern them?

Comment: splitting it applying a specific pattern, can be anything, spaces, full stop, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to rethink your problem:

Since you are trying to construct an inverted index:

1. Use [Multimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) rather then `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`

   `Multimap<word, frequency, fileName, .some thing else tomorrow>`
2. Now, read one file, construct the Multimap and save it on disk. (similar to Jon's answer)
3. After reading x files, merge all the Multimaps together: `putAll(multimap)` if you really need one common map of all the values.

Comment: hm i like your solution. What about multimap performance? putAll will merge all the multimaps. what about repeated words? Am i able to sum both frequencies (values) ?

Comment: 1. do you really need 1 huge map in memory?

Comment: no. i need to print to a file the entire corpus with words-frequency

Comment: In that case, save different multimaps and print it individually

Comment: wont work, i need to have the entire corpus. i like your solution, but how can i mix the keys at the end and sum the values on all the words?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just read one file at a time, and dump that file's results to disk, then read the next file etc? Clearly each file is independent of the others in terms of the mapping, so why keep the results of the first file while you're writing the second?

You could possibly write the results for each file to another file (e.g. foo.txt => foo.txt.map), or you could create a single file with some sort of delimiter between results, e.g.

```
==== foo.txt ====
word - 1
the - 3
get - 3
==== bar.txt ====
apple - 2
// etc
```

By the way, why are you using `double` for the frequency? Surely it should be an integer value...

Comment: because the output is the entire corpus, with words frequency. that could be done mixing at the end everything=?

Comment: @user974594: I didn't really follow that comment... but if you stored each map in its own file, sorted in alphabetical order, you could probably do something clever afterwards. It's unclear what mixing you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

The time for a hash map to process shouldn't increase significantly as it grows. It is possible that your map is skewing because of an unsuited hashing function or filling up too much. Unless you're using more RAM than you can get from the system, you shouldn't have to break things up.

What I have seen with Java when running huge hash maps (or any collection) with a lots of objects in memory is that the VM goes crazy trying to run the garbage collector. It gets to the point where 90% of the time is spent with the JVM kicking off the garbage collector which takes a while and finds almost every object has a reference.

I suggest profiling your application, and if it is the garbage collector, then increasing heap space and tuning the garbage collector. Also, it will help if you can approximate the needed size of your hash maps and provide sufficiently large allocations (see initialCapacity and loadFactor options in the constructor).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this library to improve your performance.

http://high-scale-lib.sourceforge.net/

It is similar to the java collections api, but for high performance. It would be ideal if you can batch and merge these results after processing them in small batches.

Here is an article that will help you with some more inputs.

http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue193.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a custom class,

```
public class CustomData {
 private String word;
 private double frequency;
 //Setters and Getters
}
```

and use your map as

```
Map<fileName, List<CustomData>>
```

this way atleast you will have only 900 keys in your map.

-Ivar